# Can a gamma ray photon transfer it's energy to an atom, not an electron of the atom?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics

I know that due to the photoelectric effect, when you shoot a gamma ray at an atom, it causes an electron to absorb that energy. However, can the nucleus of an atom take in that energy, instead of the electrons?

Comment: Look at the enegies of photoelectric effect https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.1662 , electron volts . Gammas are in million electron volts, short wavelength, i.e.  with very small probability of hitting an electron.

Comment: @drvrm  this is not correct terminology . It is the whole atom that s absorbing and emitting energy, not the electron. It is a synergy of the charge of the  nucleus and the charge of the electron in each other's field, as modeled by the potential in the Schrodinger equation. again, electronic levels are in electron volts, the most the gamma can do is kick out an electron because it is mev energies

Comment: @anna v -i agree with your view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes, but at common gamma-ray energies it's not very probable. At typical energies, the final state of the nucleus would be bound, and the density of available excited states would be quite low. In the photoelectric effect, you're scattering the electron into the continuum, so there are guaranteed to be states with the right energy.

Coulomb excitation is a process in which a nucleus scatters inelastically from another nucleus and excites it through electromagnetic interactions. This can be considered as excitation by a virtual gamma ray. Coulomb excitation is a very common process, often with a huge cross-section.

Comment: A 'common' process in which photo-excitation of a nucleus is employed is Mössbauer spectroscopy. In that case you know you are using (about) the right energy because you seek to reverse the decay that generated the photon in the first place.

Comment: Ben, I think that the question might not refer to an internal excitation of the nucleus by a photon. It possibly refers to the absorption of a photon by a nucleon (proton) so that the photon energy is transformed (in part) to kinetic energy of the nucleon. Just like in the photoelectric effect, or Compton scattering, to the kinetic energy of the electron.

Comment: @freecharly: That wouldn't occur at typical gamma-ray energies (~1 MeV). That's why I say in the answer that "at typical energies, the final state of the nucleus would be bound." The process you're referring to is called nuclear photodissociation.

Comment: @Ben Crowell - Thank you! So I understand that this process also exists at higher gamma-ray energy.